# Convert data type a of class object (C++)

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am writing a game in which one Object has an ability to turn into an object of another class (e.g. Clark Kent -> Superman). I would like to know what is the most efficient way to implement this.

The logic of my current code:
I have created a `turnInto()` function inside the ClarkKent class. The `turnInto` function calls the constructor of Superman class, passing all needed infos to it. The next step is to assign the address of Superman object to the current ClarkKent object.

```
void ClarkKent::turnInto() {
    Superman sMan(getName(), getMaxHP(), getDamage());
    &(*this) = &w; // <- error here
    this->ClarkKent::~ClarkKent();
}
```

As you might have guessed, the compiler gives an error that the expression is not assignable. Not sure how to find a correct solution to this.

Comment: This is begging for troubles. Keep it simple.

Comment: *The logic of my current code:* -- You cannot take an existing object `foo`, and turn it into a different object `bar`.  A `foo` is a `foo`, a `bar` is a `bar`.  You need to take a step back and come up with a better design.  Maybe a single class with a member that determines what "powers" the class has.  Change the "powers" member, then you wwould make Clark Kent into Superman.

Comment: Do not touch this and do not call the destructor.

Comment: how many Supermans / ClarkKents do you have in the game? It really sounds as if you should rething your design, maybe Superman and ClarkKent are two instances of the same class? Maybe you dont want to create a new instance but they are actually the same (did you ever see Superman and ClarkKent in the same room? ;)

Comment: Sounds more like you want to have an entity that has a role like Clark or Superman, and that you don’t want to change the entity itself but just it’s role/abilities.

Comment: This is absolutely an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You should talk about _what you're trying to do_, instead of _why your solution doesn't seem to be possible_.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and don't play tricks you don't understand with your objects.

```
Superman ClartkKent::turnInto() {
    return {getName(), getMaxHP(), getDamage()};
}
```

At the callee:

```
ClartkKent some_guy{...};
auto some_other_guy = some_guy.tunInto();
```

Or if you need something fancy:

```
using NotBatman = std::variant<ClartkKent, Superman>;
NotBatman some_guy = ClartkKent{...};
using std::swap;
swap(some_guy, some_guy.tunInto());
```

IDK

Comment: But frankly, your classes are code smells. The last time I checked, there was only one Clark Kent and one Superman; not a bunch of them.

Comment: thank you guys. I guess I really need to redesign my code. A simple bool variable seems to be a much better option in this case.

Comment: @GasperJ. Yeah. You can't change something's type, and you certainly can't do it via assignment :)